# rxjava2 - how to create an infinite integer sequence generator?

Tags: rx-java2

Using rxjava2, I am attempting to create two infinite integer stream sequences, combine the sequences together in order to create pairs and print the result.

For a reason I don't understand, my code below creates an infinite loop when the zip function is being executed. It's like the zip function is waiting for both infinite sequences to complete before starting to emit items.

How can I make the below work?

E.g.:

- seq1 = 1, 2, 3,...,infinite
- seq2 = 5, 10, 15,...,infinite
- zip(seq1,
  seq2)= (1,5), (2,10), (3,15),..., infinite

My code is as follow:

```
public Observable<Integer> intervalSequence(int start, int step)
{
    return Observable.generate(()->start,
    (s, emitter)->{
        int next = s+step;
        emitter.onNext(next);
        return next;
    });
}

public Observable<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pageRange(int pageSize){
    Observable<Integer> from = intervalSequence(1, pageSize);
    Observable<Integer> to = intervalSequence(pageSize, pageSize);
    Observable<Pair<Integer, Integer>> fromTo = Observable.zip(from, to, (f, t) -> {
        return Pair.of(f, t);
    });
    return fromTo;
}

@Test
public void pageRangeTest() throws Exception {
    //works
    intervalSequence(1, 5).take(5).doOnNext(nmb -> System.out.println(nmb)).subscribe();
    //Doesn't work
    pageRange(5).take(5).doOnNext(pair -> System.out.println("left: "+pair.getLeft()+" right: "+pair.getRight())).subscribe();
}
```

How can I make `pageRange(5).take(5).doOnNext(pair -> System.out.println("left: "+pair.getLeft()+" right: "+pair.getRight())).subscribe();` print my values?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `Flowable`.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks! It works. Your quick help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following feedback from @akarnokd, using `Flowable` instead of `Observable` solves the problem. Using `Flowable`, the working code is:

```
public Flowable<Integer> intervalSequence(int start, int step)
{
    return Flowable.generate(()->start,
    (s, emitter)->{
        int next = s+step;
        emitter.onNext(next);
        return next;
    });
}

public Flowable<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pageRange(int pageSize){
    Flowable<Integer> from = intervalSequence(1, pageSize);
    Flowable<Integer> to = intervalSequence(pageSize, pageSize);
    Flowable<Pair<Integer, Integer>> fromTo = Flowable.zip(from, to, (f, 
    t) -> {
        return Pair.of(f, t);
    });
    return fromTo;
}

@Test
public void pageRangeTest() throws Exception {
    pageRange(5).take(5).doOnNext(pair -> System.out.println("left: "+pair.getLeft()+" right: "+pair.getRight())).subscribe();
}
```